# How to replace addition with multiplication to find the next integer value?

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, arithmetic, integers

Sorry in advance for my lack of mathematical knowledge, I am very new to it.

---

Yesterday, I posed this question to myself:

"In a world without addition or subtraction, how could we derive the next value in the sequence of natural numbers from $1\to\infty$ with a step size of $1$?"

This lead me to the idea of multiplication to find the next value in a sequence.  After analyzing the multipliers between each natural value using: 
$$
\frac{(n+1)}{n}
$$

I noticed the pattern of this sequence starts at the high values of $2$ and $1.5$, then converges to a value of $1$.

---

My two questions:

- Is it right to assume that the sequence of multipliers should have a more predictable sequence?
- Are there more elegant ways of producing the next natural number without addition or subtraction?

Comment: Hi Vita. First of all let me congratulate you with your mathematical curiosity! Keep asking yourself questions like these, and never worry about whether or not they are stupid questions!

Comment: In a word without addition you do not have the expression $n+1$, so $\frac{n+1}{n}$ does not work.

Comment: notice that there are prime numbers that can't be obtained by multiplying two numbers together.

Comment: @john why not ? $p=1\cdot p$. I don't see why we need two "non-trivial numbers".

Comment: I did not think I would have to explicitly write that I mean two non trivial numbers.

Comment: How do you define "next natural number" in a world without +1?

Comment: putting the knife where it hurts

Comment: @siméon: hadn't just this been the point/the nerve of the couriosity of the OP?

Comment: Something like $n+1=\log_2(2\cdot2^n)$?

Comment: @g.kov: That's perfect! Exactly what I was looking for!  Very Nice!

Comment: @DietrichBurde: Maybe I should've phrased it as - Addition exists, but you are not allowed to use it.

Comment: @john: That is true, but in this case we're also including the set of real numbers to get the natural sequence (again I probably should've been more specific in my first post, sorry about that)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With the function $2^n$ and it's inverse,  $\log_2$ available,
$n+1=\log_2(2\cdot2^n)$.

Answer (score 5):

If we were allowed to use floor and ceiling functions in this strange world without $+$ and $-$, then perhaps we could use the following function which would generate the next integer after $n$:

$$f(n)=\lceil{(n\times\frac{\lceil n\sqrt2\rceil}{\lfloor n\sqrt2\rfloor})\rceil}$$

Comment: This is very nice!  Thank you for this answer!